# MySQL query with JOIN not using INDEX

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, database-performance, query-performance

I have the following two tables in MySQL (Simplified).

- `clicks` (InnoDB)

  - Contains around about 70,000,000 records
  - Has an index on the `date_added` column
  - Has a column `link_id` which refers to a record in the `links` table
- `links` (MyISAM)

  - Contains far fewer records, around about 65,000

I'm trying to run some analytical queries using these tables. I need to pull out some data, about clicks that occurred inside of two specified dates while applying some other user selected filters using other tables and joining them into the links table.

My question revolves around the use of indexes however. When I run the following query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1)
FROM
    clicks
WHERE
    date_added >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00'
AND date_added <= '2016-11-03 23:59:59';
```

I get a response back in 1.40 sec. Using `EXPLAIN` I find that the MySQL uses the index on the `date_added` column as expected.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(1) FROM clicks WHERE date_added >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND date_added <= '2016-11-16 23:59:59';
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clicks | range | date_added    | date_added | 4       | NULL | 1559288 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
```

However, when I `LEFT JOIN` in my `links` table I find that the query takes much longer to execute:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS clicks
FROM
    clicks AS c
LEFT JOIN links AS l ON l.id = c.link_id
WHERE
    c.date_added >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00'
AND c.date_added <= '2016-11-16 23:59:59';
```

Which completed in 6.50 sec. Using `EXPLAIN` I find that the index was not used on the `date_added` column:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(1) AS clicks FROM clicks AS c LEFT JOIN links AS l ON l.id = c.link_id WHERE c.date_added >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND c.date_added <= '2016-11-16 23:59:59';
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref           | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | range  | date_added    | date_added | 4       | NULL          | 6613278 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY    | 4       | c.link_id     |       1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+-------------+
```

As you can see the index isn't being used for the `date_added` column in the larger table and seems to take far longer. This seems to get even worse when I join in other tables.

Does anyone know why this is happening or if there's anything I can do to get it to use the index on the `date_added` column in the clicks table?

---

**Edit**

I've just attempted to get my stats out of the database using a different method. The first step in my method involves pulling out a distinct set of `link_id`s from the clicks table. I've found that I'm seeing the same problem here again, without a JOIN. The index is not being used:

My query:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(link_id) AS link_id
FROM
    clicks
WHERE
    date_added >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00'
AND date_added <= '2016-12-05 10:16:00'
```

This query took almost a minute to complete. I ran an `EXPLAIN` on this and found that the query is not using the index as I expected it would:

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clicks  | index | date_added    | link_id  | 4       | NULL | 79786609 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

I expected that it would use the index on `date_added` to filter down the result set and then pull out the distinct `link_id` values. Any idea why this is happening? I have an index on `link_id` as well as `date_added`.

Comment: please add **index** on link_id in the clicks tables that can help to reduce query output time

Comment: @SumanEStatic - `INDEX(link_id)` would _not_ help.

Comment: Smells like you are using MyISAM.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames I'm using InnoDB for my `clicks` table, and MyISAM for my `links` table.

Comment: @Jonathon, didn't noticed till date but what??? your click table and link table are on different engines? that's really strange and I doubt that's the issue here.

Comment: @Rahul Yeah, I can't remember why but the decision was made to switch the clicks table from MyISAM to InnoDB a while back. I think this was because InnoDB is better for frequent inserts and avoids table locking, which is more suitable for the clicks table. It would be relatively painless to switch to InnoDB in my links table if you think that might help?

Comment: @Jonathon, am not sure off my head but I would do a small test and confirm the same, if I were you :)

Comment: The explain shows that the `date_added` index was used even in case of the 2nd query. The `ref` being null does not mean that the index was not used. Actually, this is completely normal for an index that is used for range lookup.

Comment: Mixing Engines is OK; that was the main overhaul in version 4.1.  InnoDB is the almost-universally preferred Engine today.  There is only rarely any excuse to use MyISAM.  MyISAM will be removed in 8.0.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use an ordinary `JOIN` in place of the `LEFT JOIN`? `LEFT JOIN` preserves all the rows on the right, so it will yield the same value of `COUNT()` as the unjoined table.  If you want to count only the rows from your right-hand table that have matching rows in the left-hand table, use `JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`.

Try dropping your index on `date_added` and replacing it with a compound index on `(date_added, link_id)`. [This sort of index is called a covering inde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Covering_index)x. When the query planner knows it can get everything it needs from an index, it doesn't have to bounce back to the table. In this case the query planner can random-access the index to the beginning of your date range, then do an [index range scan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html) to the end of the range. It's still going to have to refer to the other table, though.

(**Edit**) For the sake of experimentation, try a narrower date range. See if `EXPLAIN` changes. In that case, the query planner might be guessing your date_added column's cardinality wrong.

You might try an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html).  For example, try

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS clicks
  FROM clicks AS c USE INDEX (date_added)
  LEFT JOIN links AS l ON l.id = c.link_id
 WHERE etc
```

But, judging from your `EXPLAIN` output, you're already doing a range scan on `date_added`.  Your next step, like it or not, is the compound covering index.

Make sure there's an index on `links(id)`.  There probably is, because it's probably the PK.

Try using `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(1)`. It probably won't make a difference, but it's worth a try. `COUNT(*)` simply counts rows rather than evaluating something for each row it counts.

*(Nitpick)* Your date range smells funny. Use `<` for the end of your range for best results, like so.

```
 WHERE c.date_added >= '2016-11-01'
   AND c.date_added <  '2016-11-17';
```

**Edit**: Look, the MySQL query planner uses lots of internal knowledge about how tables are structured.  And, *it can only use one index per table to satisfy a query* as of late 2016. That's a limitation.

`SELECT DISTINCT column` is actually a fairly complex query, because it has to de-dupe the `column` in question. If there's an index on that column, the query planner is likely to use it. Choosing that index means it could not choose some other index.

Compound indexes (covering indexes) sometimes *but not always* resolve this kind of index-selection dilemma, and allow index dual usage.  You can read about all this at http://use-the-index-luke.com/

But if your operational constraints prevent the adding of compound indexes, you'll need to live with the one-second query. It isn't that bad.

Of course, saying you can't add compound indexes to get your job done is like this:

*A*: stuff is falling off my truck on the freeway.

*B*: put a tarp over the stuff and tie it down.

*A*: my boss won't let me put a tarp on the truck.

*B*: well, then, drive slow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried using a `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` with no success, I've also tried `COUNT(*)` to no avail as well. I can confirm that `links(id)` is a primary key and the `clicks(link_id)` column is also indexed. I'm reluctant at the moment to make any changes to the table due to the sheer size of it, so I've not been able to drop the index and re-add a covering index as suggested. Thanks again though!

Comment: You can add the new index without dropping the existing one first.

Comment: Using `ALTER TABLE`, you can add and drop any number of indexes simultaneously.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` are synonyms; `COUNT(col)` is different in that it checks whether `col` is `NULL`.

Comment: With 5.6.7 and InnoDB, you can `ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=INPLACE`, thereby not worry about how long `ADD INDEX` takes.

Comment: (the Nitpick) -- If `date_added` is `DATETIME(6)`, you might get a different answer.  The `<` works 'correctly' in all cases.

Comment: @O.Jones I've edited my question with something else I've found that could potentially help diagnose the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Your suggestion make sense but did you see OP's comment in top which says *I'm using InnoDB for my `clicks` table, and MyISAM for my `links` table* does that raise any suspicion?

Answer (score 1):

Not absolutely sure but consider moving the condition from `WHERE` condition to `JOIN ON` condition since you are performing a outer join (`LEFT JOIN`) it makes difference in performance unlike `inner join` where the condition be it on `where` or `join on` clause is equivalent.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS clicks 
FROM clicks AS c 
LEFT JOIN links AS l ON l.id = c.link_id 
AND (c.date_added >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00' 
AND c.date_added <= '2016-11-16 23:59:59');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried moving the conditions from the WHERE clause to the JOIN ON as suggested but I'm still seeing the same issue.

Comment: Use `ON` for saying how the tables are related; use `WHERE` for filtering.  The Optimizer _may_ treat them identically.  You can see that from `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...; SHOW WARNINGS;`

Comment: @Rahul I've edited my question with something else I've found that could potentially help diagnose the problem. Thanks :)