# MySQL select distinct query not using index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, database-performance, query-performance

I have a table `clicks`:

```
CREATE TABLE `clicks` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `link_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `link_id` (`link_id`),
  KEY `date_added` (`date_added`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=90899051 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

With the following indexes:

```
+--------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| clicks |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | id          | A         |    79808649 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| clicks |          1 | link_id    |            1 | link_id     | A         |      276154 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| clicks |          1 | date_added |            1 | date_added  | A         |    79808649 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

I'm trying to run some analytical queries on this table and I'm finding that it's taking ages to run. Take the following query for example:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(link_id) AS link_id
FROM
    clicks
WHERE
    date_added >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00'
AND date_added <= '2016-12-05 10:16:00'
```

This query took almost a minute to complete. I found by running an `EXPLAIN` on the query that the indexes weren't used.

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clicks | index | date_added    | link_id | 4       | NULL | 79786609 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

I expected that the query would have been run by using the index on the `date_added` column to filter down the result set before then pulling out the distinct `link_id`s from the result.

Does anyone know why the index is not being used or if there's anything I can do to force it to be used?

Note: This question is part of a bigger issue and is closely related to an unsolved issue I posted last week - [MySQL query with JOIN not using INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933842/mysql-query-with-join-not-using-index)

---

**Edit**

Explain on my query, without using any index hints:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT(link_id) FROM clicks WHERE date_added >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND date_added <= '2016-12-05 23:59:59';
+----+-------------+---------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                     | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clicks                    | index | date_added    | link_id | 4       | NULL | 79816660 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Explain on my query WITH index hints:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT(link_id) FROM clicks USE INDEX(date_added) IGNORE INDEX(link_id) WHERE date_added >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND date_added <= '2016-12-05 23:59:59';
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clicks                    | ALL  | date_added    | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 79816882 | Using where; Using temporary |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------+
```

**Edit 2**

Using `FORCE INDEX(date_added)` on my query (Query completed even quicker, 12.05 sec):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT(link_id) FROM clicks FORCE INDEX(date_added) WHERE date_added >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND date_added <= '2016-12-05 23:59:59';
+----+-------------+---------------------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                     | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clicks                    | range | date_added    | date_added | 4       | NULL | 17277508 | Using where; Using temporary |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have you analyzed the table?

Comment: What do you get if you replace `DISTINCT(link_id)` with `count(*)`?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz The EXPLAIN statement indicates "Using index", which is what I want and I get a result in around about 3.5 seconds.

Comment: `using index` implies covering index. You need to create a multi-column index for that if you use distinct. Reason: for count(*) mysql does not need to retrieve actual field values, for a distinct it does.

Comment: What percent of the table is encompassed by the date range?  (This bears on one of your questions.)

Comment: Did it run faster? or slower? with the index hint?

Comment: Neither says `Using index`; please clarify.

Comment: The date_added in my table begins in May last year so the date range in this question covers around about 4-5% of the table. It seemed to run faster with the index hints (Around about 30s I think), although it seems that no index was used. Using `FORCE INDEX(date_added)` sped the query up further to around 12s. The lack of `Using index` was something that I though indicated the lack of a use of an index, however @Shadow below explained that this is not always the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it is not true that no index was used. The `explain` results clearly indicate that `link_id` index was used.

As to why the `date_added` index was not used, the answer is simple: MySQL decided against because it thought that `link_id` index would be a better choice.

What you need to understand is that there are 2 operations in your query that could be sped-up by an index:

1. Filtering on the data range
2. Making sure that each `link_id` is returned only once.

If you really wanted to optimise this query, then you would create a multi-column index on `link_id, date_added` fields. You wrote in a comment to Gordon's answer, that this was not possible.

Therefore, MySQL must decide which one of the 2 operations it is going to speed up using one of the indexes. It decided that `link_id` index is the better choice. If you disagree with its decision, then you can use [index hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) to indicate to MySQL that you prefer to use (`use index` or `force index`) or ignore (`ignore index`) a particular index.

Just instruct MySQL to ignore the `link_id` index and use `date_added` index. Just make sure that you check the query speed after the adjustments.

Comment: I assumed no index was used due to the lack of "Using index" in the "Extra" column. Is this incorrect? I'm thinking it may be necessary to add a composite index on those two columns but that would mean some significant downtime that I can't afford at the moment. I've tried using index hints as suggested - I don't see a difference in the output to my EXPLAIN, but I have seen a slight improvement in speed, it's almost halved. Thanks.

Comment: The `key` field of the explain output shows which index(es) is used. The extra will provide you additional information, which may explain how an index is used. I would like to see that unchanged explain result, just in case I can spot some differences :)

Comment: How to interpret the results of explain pls see MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html

Comment: Oh right, thanks for clarifying that for me. What do you mean by unchanged explain result? I'm not sure how you're able to tell, but I did slightly modify the result of the explain because our tables and columns are terribly named and I wanted to make it clear in my question. Thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to see the explain results after using the index hints?

Comment: Oh right, got you. I've updated my question with the result of my EXPLAIN statement before and after index hints were added, there is a slight difference. Thanks :)

Comment: That's very interesting in the light of you claiming that the version with index hints was faster. That explain shows that **no** index was used (`key` field is null), yet the query was faster. Can you pls try to add a `force index (date_added)` to the query, see how fast it runs and add the explain output?

Comment: I've just updated my question with the query using `FORCE INDEX(date_added)` as suggested. It seems to have ran even faster (12s)!

Comment: You can see from the `key` field of the `explain` output that `date_added` index is used for a range scan. The `using temporary` in the `extra` field indicates that MySQL used an implicit temporary table to create the distinct list, since that step is no longer supported by an index. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Also, the last explain results match you explain results in your original question, indicating that the `date_added` index was used there as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table for individual links, you could try:

```
select l.link_id
from links l
where exists (select 1
              from clicks c
              where c.link_id = l.link_id and
                    c.date_added >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00' and
                    c.date_added <= '2016-12-05 10:16:00'
             );
```

For this, you would want in index on `clicks(link_id, date_added)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however in my case I'm actually running my query to get around another problem so this isn't an option. I don't have a compound index on `link_id` and `date_added` either unfortunately and my table is too big to consider altering. Do you have any clue as to why the index isn't being used in my query? Thanks again